# Trying to use JSON to get cascading DDLs but not getting response

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, json, getjson

I'm trying to create cascading DDLs.

My aspx page:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>סוג שולחן</td>
            <td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTableType" runat="server" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>קוד שולחן</td>
            <td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTableCode" runat="server" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>הנחה קבועה לשולחן</td>
            <td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDiscounts" runat="server" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

I'm populating the first DDL from DB and that is working fine.

Now, for the second DDL i'm using this code:

```
$(document).ready(
function() 
{
    $("#ddlTableType").change(
        function() 
        { 
            $('#ddlTableCode').html('');
             var TypeID = $("#ddlTableType > option:selected").attr("value");                
                    $.getJSON('LoadTableCodes.ashx?ObjectType=' + TypeID, function(TableCodes) {
                        alert('aaaaaaaaaaaaaa');
                        $.each(TableCodes, function() {
                            alert(this['TableCode']);                         
                            $("#ddlTableCode").append($("<option></option>").val(this['TableCode']).html(this['TableCode']));
                        });
                    });
        }
    );
}
```

);

When i'm browsing to LoadTablesCodes with a typeId im getting the JSON resould. This is working...

My problem is with the js code i think, my **$.getJSON** function is not working (can't even get the alert inside the function to pop).

Please, what am i doing wrong?

10x

Comment: t-shooting tips: (1) is .change() being called at all? (2) use fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to check whether the json request was sent, and whether a reply came back.

Comment: Yes, change() is being called, when i put the alert befor the getJSON the pops...

Comment: Did you try Firebug? http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: oopppsss, sorry guys, got it solved, i changed the jason, has a little (comma) mistake over there and every thing is working (with JQUERY 1.3.2 not the 1.4!!! the 1.4 is not working for the same thing)...10x

Comment: You should post your fix as the answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was with jquery 1.4.2, In my searches i'v read that 1.4 fails silently in all the procces can't finish, i went back to 1.3 and every thing was working, i've got a very simple error at the end wich i corrected and it working....
10x